# ThreeJS - wrong light rotation

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, blender, collada

The following issue occurs regardless of importing the scene, or creating every mesh and light by code.

My scene consists of a plane, a cube and a spot light.
The spot light is rotated 45 degrees on the y-axis.
In example 1 it is located at point (4, 0, 4).
In example 2 it is located at point (4, 0, 5).

The rotation of the light is always 45 degress (0.785398163 radians).

Why does the light always point to the center of the front cube face?
I would assume it would render example 2 exactly as shown in blender, pointing to the edge of the cube.

Here are the examples:

**First Example (correct rotation):**

I have this scene in Blender:
[image]

It renders this way with ThreeJS:
[image]

**Second example (wrong rotation):**

I have this scene in Blender:
[image]

It renders this way in ThreeJS:
[image]

Comment: `SpotLights` in three.js do not use the `light.rotation` property for anything. Instead, they use `light.target`, which is an `Object3D`. Is `light.target.position` equal to the origin in both cases?

Comment: The target position is (0, 0, 0) in each case, which explains the behaviour. Thank you very much.

Comment: how to enable light debug to see which direction it has??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpotLights` in three.js do not use their `rotation` property for anything. Instead, they use `light.target`, which is an `Object3D`.

three.js r.68